# Show Attachment in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
@AuraEnabled
public static list<Attachment> getImagesOfkey(){
    return [select Id,parentid,Name, ContentType from Attachment where parentid='a0D0q000001O0pPEAS'];
}
```

JS

```
 let result =await getImagesOfkey({})
        this.Images = JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log('this.Images' + result);
```

How to show Attachments in Lightning Web Component which i have uploaded in my custom object and i want to show it on Lightning Web Component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an apex controller from a working example; https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/06/custom-file-upload-in-lightning-web.html

```java
    public inherited sharing class LWCExampleController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static ContentVersion saveFile(Id idParent, String strFileName, String base64Data) {
        // Decoding base64Data
        base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');

        // inserting file
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.Title = strFileName;
        cv.PathOnClient = '/' + strFileName;
        cv.FirstPublishLocationId = idParent;
        cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
        cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
        Insert cv;
        return cv;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<contentversion> releatedFiles(Id idParent){
        list<id> lstConDocs = new list<id>();
        for(ContentDocumentLink cntLink : [Select Id, ContentDocumentId From ContentDocumentLink Where LinkedEntityId =:idParent]) {
            lstConDocs.add(cntLink.ContentDocumentId);
        }
        if(!lstConDocs.isEmpty()) {
            return [SELECT Id, Title, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :lstConDocs];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }

    }

}


  [1]: https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/06/custom-file-upload-in-lightning-web.html
```

Comment: want to show the Image not the name

Comment: Show the image of the attachment as a thumbnail, or do you want to show an icon?

Comment: as thumbnail i want to show

Comment: hello there i jus like this but my file is saving in byte but in my pc it is 200kb